# Saga alternative for Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, redux-saga

I finished learning Vue.js, it has had almost all I wanted from it!
But I can't find something similar to redux-saga. It was a very great tool, and it would be nice to have something like this.

Can someone propose **alternative library**, or **share experience how to manage big projects with complex data-flow without redux-saga**.

Did someone try to connect Redux-saga to Vue and use it (e.g. with [that](https://medium.com/@xanf/vuex-meets-redux-saga-e9c6b46555e) library)?
What was the experience?

Comment: You have https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-saga, not sure if it fits your need, haven't used it personally.

Comment: I've saw it, but it is not even close to redux-saga. And there are no such method as  'take'
So probably main question how can I track that some action/mutation was finished.

Comment: I've never used Vue, so I am not sure if it makes sense, but redux-saga can run without react/redux using the runSaga function. https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/UsingRunSaga.html ... maybe you can somehow use that to have sagas in vue?

Comment: Yes you are right, [here](https://medium.com/@xanf/vuex-meets-redux-saga-e9c6b46555e) is small article how to do it and even small library to do it for you.

Comment: @Arseniy-II - duplicate doesn't necessarily means which question asked first, but if the same question have been answered.

Answer (score 2):

Have the same problem. I created new package called [vuex-coolstory](https://github.com/niklv/vuex-coolstory) cause other packages is outdated.

Plus I did not use vuex actions to dispatch saga actions. I created new function `store.sagaDispatch()` and `mapSagaActions()` helper function for that. 
I had to stop using vuex actions for saga actions, cause I must define them in store. And there are will be a lot unused empty functions. If you not define it in store, vuex print error message every time when you dispact action.